# Are there real chemistry bottles with this kind of label?

Tags: safety, chemistry-in-fiction

I watched a movie recently which had a close-up of this weird bottle:

[image: screenshot]

The way it reads is very strange to me. Is this just complete movie nonsense, or are there really bottles in real life sold with such strange labels full of exclamation marks and whatnot?

Comment: Hehe haha … no.

Comment: It is not fluoroantimonic acid (CAS Number 16,950-06-4). And IUPAC names are not registered trademarks.

Comment: Is that a glass  bottle? "[fluoroantimonic acid] cannot be contained directly in glass carboys, as it attacks glass." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluoroantimonic_acid Also note spelling, *flouroantimonic* [sic].

Comment: @DrMoishePippik It could some special ingredient for making antimony-containing bread. ;-)

Answer (score 5):

Something is not right. Not chemical, at least. *Fluoroantimonic* has *u* before *o*; the label on the questionable bottle has *o* before *u*. And *Salvadeo Company Inc.* does not come up on a google search.

There is some reality to the image, however. A search for fluoroantimonic acid brings up an image for Magic Acid (a blend of fluorosulfuric acid and antimony pentafluoride: Ref 1) which has some common elements: the number 17,508-0 (top center) seems to be a catalog number for 100g of the material. The OP's image and this one also contain the words *spectrograde*, *Freeze!*, *Corrosive!*, *Hygroscopic!*, and *Store under nitrogen* in similar positions. And with a red border. So the OP's image could be a label for Magic Acid that was promoted in acidic strength to Fluoroantimonic Acid and assigned to Salvadeo Company, but misspelled.

[image]

The bottle in the OP's image does seem to be glass, so it would not be appropriate for Fluoroantimonic Acid. The YouTube video (Ref 2) says that fluoroantimonic acid must be contained in a Teflon bottle (see image below for 50g).

[image]

Magic Acid (being only the *second* most acidic superacid) might be contained in glass. But the ingredient listed on the OP's label is incompatible with the material of the container.

Ref 1.https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_acid

Ref 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWBNcMyfiGQ

Comment: So, ultimately, the answer to the title question is an unqualified Yes. Seems like the prop department knows their stuff…

Comment: @JonCuster, not unless they learn to spell: it's *flour*antimonic acid on the label.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik - pretty harsh on some (almost certainly) non-chemists to get that close...

Comment: Well, I'd be concerned whether malic or maleic acid is used in a a flavored apple tart ;-)